# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')"

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have got this error when I am trying to get product details from database.
My productDetails.jd file:

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from "react";
import Carousel from "react-material-ui-carousel";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getProductDetails } from "../../actions/productAction";

const ProductDetails = ({ match }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { product, loading, error } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.productDetails
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProductDetails(match.params.id));
  }, [dispatch, match.params.id]);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="ProductDetails">
        <div>
          <Carousel>
            {product.images &&
              product.images.map((item, i) => (
                <img
                  className="CarouselImage"
                  key={item.url}
                  src={item.url}
                  alt={`${i} Slide`}
                />
              ))}
          </Carousel>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ProductDetails;
```

and my productAction.js file:

```
import axios from "axios";
import {
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
} from "../constants/productConstants";

// Get Products Details
export const getProductDetails = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST });

    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/v1/product/${id}`);

    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data.product,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
      payload: error.response.data.message,
    });
  }
};
};
```

and lastly my app.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import ProductDetails from "./component/Product/ProductDetails";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/product/:id" element={<ProductDetails />} />
      </Routes>

    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am a beginner in MERN stack and I have understood that it's a react-router-dom versions issue, I am using version: 6.4.0 and it doesn't support "match" but I don't know how to solve this issue.
Someone please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the `useParams` hook in the `ProductDetails` component.